# I can't login to facebook in dragonvale

Tags: dragonvale

In the new update of Dragonvale, there are no icon in the option menu that I can login to facebook. And my old park is on the account. What am I suposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Log into facebook and search "Dragonvale" and click play. It should bring you to your app then click "link with facebook" when it pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your settings, press notifications > mobile push. It'll show a page where each App is listed and has an on/off switch next to it. Make sure Dragonvale's switch is on, then go to the app and see if it logs you in. Hope it helps.