# No "login with Facebook" option

Tags: android, dragonvale

I've made sure I'm running the latest version of Dragonvale on a Galaxy Nexus, but I can't see any "Login with Facebook" option in the options screen.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does this help? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/130811/i-cant-login-to-facebook-in-dragonvale

Comment: Thanks... i tried that but it didn't work - that other question appears to be IOS related, as I couldn't find a "Notifications -> mobile push". And I tried the other solution as well, with no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the account was setup with a child's birthday, so they weren't old enough to be sharing things using Facebook.

I deleted, and reinstalled the app and setup the account for myself using my birth date, and the option showed up!